# Can't get header AUTHORIZATION but change to AUTHORIZATIO can get value

Tags: http-headers, phalcon, jwt

In Micro Framework.

```
curl -i -X GET -H "AUTHORIZATION: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InRlc3QiLCJleHAiOjE0MTUyODg0NzgsImxhc3QiOjEzNTY5OTk1MjR9.-xysOSRcj5hgG1iMVfZWHuz39dEpvod0O5ry3EiBstg" http://localhost/contract/dist/api/v1/cue
```

When call $app->request->getHeader("AUTHORIZATION"); get null.

```
curl -i -X GET -H "AUTHORIZATIO: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InRlc3QiLCJleHAiOjE0MTUyODg0NzgsImxhc3QiOjEzNTY5OTk1MjR9.-xysOSRcj5hgG1iMVfZWHuz39dEpvod0O5ry3EiBstg" http://localhost/contract/dist/api/v1/cue
```

But $app->request->getHeader("AUTHORIZATIO"); can get value. How to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's Apache problem. I'm fix by add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

near top of .htaccess